# Get current URL SAFELY

Tags: php, url

I know there are a lot of questions about it, but I want to know how to get the current URL safely with PHP. I need it to display in the `og:url` meta tag.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what the 'safe' way is, because everywhere I look people say that it's not safe to get the current URL.

Comment: How come it is not safe?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

This will give you the complete `URL`.